# I want a variable/field to only be declared when a specific condition is true. I used Compiler Directives. Is the code I wrote valid?

Tags: unity, c#

I want a field I declared (`float attackRange`) to be only declared when inheriting class set "`bool haveLongRangeAttack`" is set to `true`. I wanted to use ***Compiler Directives*** for this purpose. Here is the code I wrote;

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class Enemy<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : Enemy<T>
{
    [SerializeField] protected bool haveCloseRangeAttack = false,
                                    haveLongRangeAttack = false;
#if haveLongRangeAttack == true
    [SerializeField] protected float attackRange = 1f;
#endif

    [SerializeField] protected GameObject mainCharacter = null;
    protected GameObject enemy = null;

    protected virtual void ChasePlayer()
    {
        if(haveCloseRangeAttack)
        {
            //...
        }
        else if(haveLongRangeAttack)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

---

I don't know if it is right way to/of *do what I want* or *using **Compiler Directives*** so please review my code and tell me if there is a problem, or if there is a better way.

It was before 6 months when I started *writing* code, and C was my first language. I am trying to learn new things/*concepts* and writing at my own style. So *there will be another way* (**maybe more efficient**); if there is one, please teach me. I'm working on my own Game Project right now, I'm open to learn new things that will benefit me...

***TY for taking time ^.^!***

***PS:****There is no **compiler-directives** tag in Tags section. Maybe it will be useful to add this tag.*

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? What you're written isn't valid (unless there's some Unity-specific extension to the preprocessor at play here). If you trying to accomplish something specific I can probably offer you an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `#if` preprocessor directive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) can be used to check if specific preprocessor symbols are defined or not. Those symbols include certain predetermined ones (such as `DEBUG`) as long as whatever you define with `#define` or the `-define` switch to the compiler itself.

You cannot use the preprocessor to check for the existence of a *field* or any other sort of member within a generic parameter.

One way you could solve this problem is through the use of interfaces: create an interface `IHasLongRangeAttack` which mandates the behavior of an entity with a long-range attack, and implement that interface on enemies that need it.

An alternative is to use composition instead of inheritance to define your objects, creating a `LongRangeAttackBehavior` object or similar; enemies with long-range attacks have an instance of this type assigned to that field, enemies without leave it null.

The latter is probably what I'd suggest.

Comment: This is about my 6th month in programming and I'm new to OOP to. C was my first language so when I try to solve a problem in OOP concept, solution doesn't come that quickly :). I wanted to optimize code by preventing unnecessary codes and wanted to learn if this will solve problem, also learn something about Preprocessor Directives too. After writing this question, I writed code from start, from a new perspective. Anyway, thanks for advice! I don't have any practice with Interfaces, I will check them out. Oh also, can you tell me more about 'composition'?